# how to solve jsx syntax error in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, syntax, jsx

Failed to compile

./src/index.js
SyntaxError: C:\wamp\www\React-applications\accordion\src\index.js: Unexpected token (8:17)

6 |
7 |     return ( < div > <

> 8 |         div data - accordion > {
> |                  ^
> 9 |             data.map((tab, index) => {
> 10 |                 const isActive = index === activeIndex
> 11 |

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

```js
function Accordion({ data, position = "top" }) {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)

    return ( <div data-accordion > {
            data.map((tab, index) => {
                const isActive = index === activeIndex

                const title = (<div data-panel-title className={isActive ? 'expanded' : ''}
                    onClick = {
                        () => setActiveIndex(index)
                    }>
                        <span> { tab.label } </span> 
                        <span> { tab.icon } </span>
                    </div>
                )

                const content = ( 
                    <div className="data-panel-content"
                    className={ isActive ? 'expanded' : '' } > 
                        { tab.content } 
                    </div>
                )

                return ( 
                   <Fragment key={index} > {position === 'bottom' ? [content, title] : [title, content]} 
                   </Fragment>
                )
            })
        } 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to add more details, error information is not sufficient to understand this. Add your code here in which you are getting this error

Comment: my data-accordion returns an syntax error on visual studio code. is it requires an extension to be insatlled ?or else how to use data variable in my code?

Comment: Did you install babel? It seems like the babel is not installed

Comment: yes i had, but i removed to test

Comment: Can you post the block of code where you are getting this issue

Comment: Please post the full code.

Comment: ya, thats it, i have installed and reloaded. My code works good.